# Python increment variable when condition is true

Tags: python

I've created a rock,paper,sciccors game in python with video recognition. I want to keep track of the win,lose and draw streaks with a counter for every situation (Win counter, lose counter and draw counter). In my code I've added the logic to increment the draw counter by one when there is a draw. I tested this to print my draw counter after playing 2 draws and the counter printed '158'.
I tested it again but played only one draw and now it returns '79'..
So it seems that my counter += 1 is somehow changed to counter =+ 79

any ideas how to make it increment by one?

My code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import mediapipe as mp

username1 = input("Enter username:")
username2 = input("Enter username:")

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands

# bepaal of een handgebaar schaar, steen of papier is
def getHandMove(hand_landmarks):
    landmarks = hand_landmarks.landmark
    if all([landmarks[i].y < landmarks[i+3].y for i in range(9,20,4)]):return "steen"
    elif landmarks[13].y < landmarks[16].y and landmarks[17].y < landmarks[20].y:return "schaar"
    else: return "papier"

# connectie met webcam
vid = cv.VideoCapture(0)

# klok
clock = 0
p1_move = p2_move = None
gameText = ""
success = True

# Win Counter
wcounter = 0

# Lose Counter
lcounter = 0

# Draw Counter
dcounter = 0

# trackt de camera voor handen en plaats 'landmarks' op de handen voor tracking
with mp_hands.Hands(model_complexity=0,
                    min_detection_confidence=0.5,   
                    min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as hands:
    while True:
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        if not ret or frame is None: break
        frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        
        results = hands.process(frame,)
        
        frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for hand_landsmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, 
                                          hand_landsmarks,
                                          mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                                          mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
                                          mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())
                
        # start van het spel        
        if 0 <= clock < 60:
            success = True
            gameText = "Ready?"
        elif clock < 80: gameText = "schaar"
        elif clock < 100: gameText = "steen"
        elif clock < 120: gameText = "papier"
        elif clock == 120: 
            # vraagt de resultaten van de handgebaren
            hls = results.multi_hand_landmarks
            if hls and len(hls) == 2:
                p1_move = getHandMove(hls[0])
                p2_move = getHandMove(hls[1])
            else: 
                success = False
        elif clock < 200:
            if success:
                # Toont aan welke speler welk handgebaar gebruikte
                gameText = f"{username1} koos voor {p1_move}. {username2} koos voor {p2_move}."
                if p1_move == p2_move: gameText = f"{gameText} gelijkspel!"; dcounter = (dcounter +1)
    
                # De voorwaarden waaraan {username1} moet voldoen om te winnen
                elif p1_move == "papier" and p2_move == "steen": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                elif p1_move == "steen" and p2_move == "schaar": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                elif p1_move == "schaar" and p2_move == "papier": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                # Als aan geen enkele bovenstaande voorwaarde wordt voldaan, dan wint {username2}
                else: gameText = f"{gameText} {username2} wint!"
            else:
                gameText = "Ongeldig"
                
        # Plaatsen van de tekst op het frame
        cv.putText(frame, f"Clock: {clock}", (50,50), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (0,255,255), 2, cv.LINE_AA)
        cv.putText(frame, gameText, (50,80), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0,255,255), 2, cv.LINE_AA)
        clock = (clock + 1) % 200
        
        # Spiegelt het scherm zodat {username1} links staat en {username2} rechts ipv default omgekeerd
        cv.flip(frame, 1)
        
        # Rendert het frame
        cv.imshow('frame', frame)
        
        #verbreek de loop door op de q toets te drukken
        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break
    
vid.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()

print(dcounter)
```

Comment: Based on the apparent simplicity of this issue, it seems like you aren't using a debugger to debug your own code; I highly recommend learning how to do that. It's free and easy and something that every developer should learn from day 1; how to step through their own code line-by-line in a debugger: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: dcounter isn't incremented in your code. Please point us to the right place.

Comment: if p1_move == p2_move: gameText = f"{gameText} gelijkspel!"; dcounter = (dcounter +1)

Comment: I've placed the counter and it's value on the game screen itself and it starten incrementing with the clock

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the problem

The reason why it was counting to 79 each game was because it was inside a while loop and in a statement that repeated itself for 79 times.
So instead of doing this:

```
 elif clock < 200:
            if success:
                # Toont aan welke speler welk handgebaar gebruikte
                gameText = f"{username1} koos voor {p1_move}. {username2} koos voor {p2_move}."
                if p1_move == p2_move: gameText = f"{gameText} gelijkspel!"; dcounter +=1

                # De voorwaarden waaraan {username1} moet voldoen om te winnen
                elif p1_move == "papier" and p2_move == "steen": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                elif p1_move == "steen" and p2_move == "schaar": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                elif p1_move == "schaar" and p2_move == "papier": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                # Als aan geen enkele bovenstaande voorwaarde wordt voldaan, dan wint {username2}
                else: gameText = f"{gameText} {username2} wint!"
            else:
                gameText = "Ongeldig"
```

I did this:

```
 elif clock == 121:
            if success:
                # Toont aan welke speler welk handgebaar gebruikte
                gameText = f"{username1} koos voor {p1_move}. {username2} koos voor {p2_move}."
                if p1_move == p2_move: gameText = f"{gameText} gelijkspel!"; dcounter +=1

                # De voorwaarden waaraan {username1} moet voldoen om te winnen
                elif p1_move == "papier" and p2_move == "steen": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                elif p1_move == "steen" and p2_move == "schaar": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                elif p1_move == "schaar" and p2_move == "papier": gameText = f"{gameText} {username1} wint!"
                # Als aan geen enkele bovenstaande voorwaarde wordt voldaan, dan wint {username2}
                else: gameText = f"{gameText} {username2} wint!"
            else:
                gameText = "Ongeldig"
```